# when I increase window width then margin will increase and when i decrease window width margin will reduce

Tags: javascript, dom

```
let getElement = document.getElementById("resize");
      let width = window.innerWidth;
      let arr = [];
      arr.push(width);
      let x = 1;
      window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        arr.reduce((current, old) => {
          if (current) {
            getElement.style.marginTop = `${(x += 1)}px`;
          } else {
            getElement.style.marginTop = `${(x -= 1)}px`;
          }
        }, width - 1);
      });
```

if current value margin will increase and if old value margin will reduce

Comment: What is the logic you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
let getElement = document.getElementById("resize");
let arr = [window.innerWidth];
let x = 1;

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let diff = width - arr[arr.length - 1];

  if (diff > 0) {
    x += 1;
  } else if (diff < 0) {
    x -= 1;
  }

  getElement.style.marginTop = `${x}px`;

  arr.push(width);
});
```